# JsonPath alternative for testing JSON output

Tags: java, json, unit-testing, jsonpath

I'm working on writing some tests for a function that takes some user supplied data and returns a JSON string based on a template. Up until now, I have simply been doing assertions that compare the entire output string against an 'expected' json document. It works, but the tests are brittle. Any change to the output requires updating the expected document, even if the change is unrelated to what is being tested.

What I should be doing is making assertions against specific sections of the json output, but I am struggling to find a library that does what I want. JsonPath can get the job done, but the syntax is unwieldy. I know where the particular data I want to test is, but trying to craft the exact JsonPath query string to retrieve it is a time consuming slog.

What I'm hoping to find is a library that allows me to add a 'tag' comment to a json element that I can use in my tests to get the exact data I need. Something like:

```
            {
                "elementType": "formInputHidden",
                "name": "message_id",
                "value": "274"
            },
            {
              "elementType": "formInputHidden",
              "name": "message_status",
              "value": "PENDING_MODERATOR_APPROVAL"
            }
```

Then in my test I could do a lookup like:

```
Object result = jsonFind.get(jsonOutput, "name", "message_id");
//result="274"
```

Does anything like this exist?

Comment: Jayway jsonpath is the goto for java.  Have you looked at that already?

Comment: What is `#123` in your data?  What you posted isn't exactly JSON.

Comment: @gregsdennis Good point. I forgot that JSON doesn't actually allow comments, even if the IDE lets me get away with it.

Comment: "library that allows me to add" - If you're looking for something that's going to mutate the data, JSON Path isn't what you're looking for.  That's a query syntax; it doesn't do mutations or transformations.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

You may try library *Josson & Jossons*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

**Josson Query**

The corresponding *Josson* query is simple.

```
Josson jossonData = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "[" +
    "    {" +
    "        \"elementType\": \"formInputHidden\"," +
    "        \"name\": \"message_id\"," +
    "        \"value\": \"274\"" +
    "    }," +
    "    {" +
    "        \"elementType\": \"formInputHidden\"," +
    "        \"name\": \"message_status\"," +
    "        \"value\": \"PENDING_MODERATOR_APPROVAL\"" +
    "    }" +
    "]");
System.out.println(jossonData.getString("[name='message_status'].value"));
// Output: PENDING_MODERATOR_APPROVAL
```

**Jossons Statement**

*Jossons* supports multiple datasets manipulation.  Therefore, dataset name qualifier is required in the statement.

```
Jossons jossons = new Jossons();
jossons.putDataset("json", jossonData);
JsonNode node = jossons.evaluateStatement("json->[name='message_status'].value");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
// Output: PENDING_MODERATOR_APPROVAL
```

**Dynamic Jossons Statement**

Changing the evaluation criteria to placeholders.

```
jossons.putDataset("k", new TextNode("name"));
jossons.putDataset("v", new TextNode("message_status"));
System.out.println(jossons.fillInPlaceholder("{{json->[{{k}}={{v->q()}}].value}}"));
// Output: PENDING_MODERATOR_APPROVAL
```